# What does the term ' a wind from God' as used at Genesis 1:2 (NRSVCE) imply?

Tags: catholicism, genesis, creation, spirit, holy

Genesis 1:2 (NRSVCE) reads :

> the earth was a formless void and darkness covered the face of the deep, while a wind from God swept over the face of the waters.

The same verse in New King James Version (NKJV)reads:

> The earth was without form, and void; and darkness was on the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God was hovering over the face of the waters.

I wish to know if the term ' a wind from God' as used in NRSVCE implies the Holy Spirit, or does it only mean a creative energy which set the stage for the creation of primordial life in water? What do the teachings of Catholic Church tell about the latter prospect?

Comment: Pope Benedict [wrote a good meditation](https://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Catholic-Understanding-Ressourcement-Retrieval/dp/0802841066) on Genesis that might contain the answer

Comment: The translational part of this question [has been addressed on Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/19361/3555). (I'm not suggesting that it can't also be a productive Q&A here.)